# when i click on category filter on Category List page Category filter getting error "Bucket does not exist"

Tags: magento2.2

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): Bucket does not exist

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): Bucket does not exist
#0 root\generated\code\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor.php(115): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->getFacetedData('category')
#1 root\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Layer\Filter\Category.php(111): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->getFacetedData('category')
#2 root\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php(202): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category->_getItemsData()
#3 root\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php(159): Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->_initItems()
#4 root\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php(148): Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItems()
#5 root\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItemsCount()
#6 root\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag.php(23): Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->canShowOptions(Array)
#7 root\vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\Block\Navigation.php(110): Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->isEnabled(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\Interceptor), Array)
#8 root\vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\templates\layer\view.phtml(18): Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation->canShowBlock()
#9 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include('C:\\wamp64\\www\\c...')
#10 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation), 'C:/wamp64/www/c...', Array)
#11 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/wamp64/www/c...')
#12 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#13 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#14 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('catalog.leftnav')
#15 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav')
#16 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav')
#17 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('catalog.leftnav', true)
#18 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('catalog.leftnav')
#19 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('sidebar.main')
#20 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('sidebar.main')
#21 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('sidebar.main')
#22 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('sidebar.main', true)
#23 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('sidebar.main')
#24 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('div.sidebar.mai...')
#25 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('div.sidebar.mai...')
#26 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('div.sidebar.mai...')
#27 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('div.sidebar.mai...', true)
#28 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('div.sidebar.mai...')
#29 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#30 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#31 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#32 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#33 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#34 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.container')
#35 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.container')
#36 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.container')
#37 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.container', true)
#38 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.container')
#39 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#40 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#41 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#42 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#43 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#44 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#45 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#46 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#47 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#48 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#49 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrap')
#50 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrap')
#51 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrap')
#52 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrap', true)
#53 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrap')
#54 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#55 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#56 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#57 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#58 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#59 root\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#60 root\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#61 root\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#62 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#63 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#64 root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#65 root\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#66 root\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#67 root\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#68 root\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#69 root\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#70 root\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#71 root\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#72 {main}
```

Comment: After setting Anchored to Yes, if it doesn't works then doing indexing bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product should works.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the category to Anchored -> 'Yes'. 
If it's already 'Yes', then set it to 'No' and again save as 'Yes'. This should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing same problem. And while I haven't found a permanent fix yet, a work around I did find is by making the sub categories anchors as well.
In my case, the resulting URL isn't SEO optimized (category.html?car=NUMBER) but at least the page doesn't break entirely.

Comment: I experience this with a 2.3.0 install, your workaround is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Pratik Kamani Hi, i have also tried this but still the issue is there. I have also tried reindexing the category.

Answer (score 0):

In the Magento admin configuration, there is a setting called "Allow All Products per Page" located under the Catalog menu and within the Storefront section. This setting determines whether customers can view all products on a single page or if there is a limit to the number of products displayed per page.

I faced the same issue, but the error was rectified after making some changes:

To make the necessary change in the Magento admin configuration, you simply need to navigate to **Catalog -> Storefront -> Allow All Products per Page** and set the value to '**No**'.